# How to find what caused a DOM element appearance change when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's [this page](http://codecanyon.net/item/bookly-responsive-wordpress-appointment-booking-and-scheduling-plugin/full_screen_preview/7226091), click next to go to the time slots [image] page. If you hover over any time slot like the one shown here, the appearance changes. I checked in Chrome's dev tools and couldn't find a style with a hover declaration nor an attached Javescript mouse over event.

How does the style get changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time slot has a `hover` style attached to it.

```
.ab-columnizer .ab-available-hour:hover {
  border: 2px solid #f4662f!important;
  color: #f4662f!important;
}
```

[image]
How to find?

1. Inspect that element
2. Right click and select force state
3. You will find :hover

Answer (score 0):

[image]

see the red rectangle, you can click the middle button and checked **:hover** checkbox then you will find the reason.